# nslookup problems when disable recusion and forwarders

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, windows

I had been getting errors looking up external sites (ex. yahoo.com) using `nslookup` on one of my member workstations.  After trying `nslookup` specifying our other DNS server (call it serverB), `nslookup` resolved successfully.

I went to the DNS configuration on the first server that was unsuccessful for resolving nslookups and noticed that under the DNS configuration, on the Advanced tab, the option 'Disable Recursion (also disables forwarders)' was checked, whereas on serverB (the good one), it wasn't.  So although this was the 'problem', I think our admins had recursion on serverA disabled for a reason.

My question is: is it a bad practice to have two DNS servers for our domain, but have one with forwarding turned off?   And is there a way to specify serverB as the primary so that `nslookup` will work without having to specify the server?

Comment: Why don't you ask the admins why recursion was disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is is this a bad practice to have two DNS servers for our domain, but have one with forwarding turned off?

Depends.  Not enough information to say, one way or the other.

Maybe it's accessible from the outside, and they don't want it being used for an amplified DDoS attack.  Maybe the additional DNS traffic generated by recursive lookups was causing network congestion.  Maybe an admin got drunk and ticked the wrong box.  Maybe an admin was using the production network to study for an MSCE.  Could be a lot of reasons, and without knowing the reason(s) for the existing configuration, we can't really say.

> Is there a way to specify serverB as the primary so that nslookup will work without having to specify the server?

Yes.  Make the IP of the server you want to use your `Preferred DNS server`.

[image]